# GeoServer returns blank image (completely transparent)

Tags: geoserver, wms, sld, image

I have a recent issue occur where for certain styles GeoServer is returning blank, completely transparent images.
See [here](https://nrri-atlas.d.umn.edu/geoserver/ows?&service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=nra%3Anwi_update_statewide_circ39&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&srs=EPSG%3A3857&tiled=true&tilesorigin=-180%2C90&width=256&height=256&bbox=-10476153.348653119,5789646.270432392,-10473707.363747992,5792092.255337515) for an example.

GeoServer version is 2.17.2

This is occurring with `GetMap` requests from the browser (as above), client applications, in the Style Editor Layer Preview, everywhere.

I turned the logging level up to GEOTOOLS_DEVELOPER, but didn't see anything unusual (that I could pick out), and certainly no errors.

Any idea what could be causing this? And how to fix it?

##### Update

Here is the SLD definition for this style:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.0.0">
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>Style1</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>Style1</sld:Name>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
        <sld:FeatureTypeName>nwi_statewide</sld:FeatureTypeName>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>Seasonally flooded basin or flat</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>circ39_class</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#fffebd</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>Wet meadow</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>circ39_class</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#e5ffb9</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>Shallow marsh</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>circ39_class</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>3</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#92daf0</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>Deep marsh</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>circ39_class</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#bcd0ff</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>Shallow open water</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>circ39_class</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#bfe8fa</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>Shrub swamp</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>circ39_class</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>6</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#ab6f01</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>Wooded swamps</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>circ39_class</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>7</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#72b06d</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>Bogs</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>circ39_class</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>8</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#740e8e</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>Municipal and industrial activities</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>circ39_class</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>80</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#f80600</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>Riverine systems</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>circ39_class</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>90</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#0050b0</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Also, here is the log for [this request](https://nrri-atlas.d.umn.edu/geoserver/ows?&service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=nra%3Anwi_update_statewide_circ39&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&srs=EPSG%3A3857&tiled=true&tilesorigin=-180%2C90&width=256&height=256&bbox=-10476153.348653119,5789646.270432392,-10473707.363747992,5792092.255337515):

```
2022-05-27 11:54:32,019 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /ows, QueryString: service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=nra:nwi_update_statewide_circ39&format=image/png&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&srs=EPSG:3857&width=500&height=500&bbox=-10476153.348653119,5789646.270432392,-10473707.363747992,5792092.255337515'; against '/web/**'
2022-05-27 11:54:32,020 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /ows, QueryString: service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=nra:nwi_update_statewide_circ39&format=image/png&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&srs=EPSG:3857&width=500&height=500&bbox=-10476153.348653119,5789646.270432392,-10473707.363747992,5792092.255337515'; against '/gwc/rest/web/**'
2022-05-27 11:54:32,020 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /ows, QueryString: service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=nra:nwi_update_statewide_circ39&format=image/png&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&srs=EPSG:3857&width=500&height=500&bbox=-10476153.348653119,5789646.270432392,-10473707.363747992,5792092.255337515'; against '/'
2022-05-27 11:54:32,020 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /ows, QueryString: service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=nra:nwi_update_statewide_circ39&format=image/png&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&srs=EPSG:3857&width=500&height=500&bbox=-10476153.348653119,5789646.270432392,-10473707.363747992,5792092.255337515'; against '/j_spring_security_check'
2022-05-27 11:54:32,020 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /ows, QueryString: service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=nra:nwi_update_statewide_circ39&format=image/png&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&srs=EPSG:3857&width=500&height=500&bbox=-10476153.348653119,5789646.270432392,-10473707.363747992,5792092.255337515'; against '/j_spring_security_check/'
2022-05-27 11:54:32,020 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /ows, QueryString: service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=nra:nwi_update_statewide_circ39&format=image/png&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&srs=EPSG:3857&width=500&height=500&bbox=-10476153.348653119,5789646.270432392,-10473707.363747992,5792092.255337515'; against '/j_spring_security_logout'
2022-05-27 11:54:32,020 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /ows, QueryString: service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=nra:nwi_update_statewide_circ39&format=image/png&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&srs=EPSG:3857&width=500&height=500&bbox=-10476153.348653119,5789646.270432392,-10473707.363747992,5792092.255337515'; against '/j_spring_security_logout/'
2022-05-27 11:54:32,020 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /ows, QueryString: service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=nra:nwi_update_statewide_circ39&format=image/png&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&srs=EPSG:3857&width=500&height=500&bbox=-10476153.348653119,5789646.270432392,-10473707.363747992,5792092.255337515'; against '/rest/**'
2022-05-27 11:54:32,020 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /ows, QueryString: service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=nra:nwi_update_statewide_circ39&format=image/png&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&srs=EPSG:3857&width=500&height=500&bbox=-10476153.348653119,5789646.270432392,-10473707.363747992,5792092.255337515'; against '/gwc/rest/**'
2022-05-27 11:54:32,020 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /ows, QueryString: service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=nra:nwi_update_statewide_circ39&format=image/png&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&srs=EPSG:3857&width=500&height=500&bbox=-10476153.348653119,5789646.270432392,-10473707.363747992,5792092.255337515'; against '/**'
2022-05-27 11:54:32,020 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Request matched by universal pattern '/**'
2022-05-27 11:54:32,020 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /ows, QueryString: service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=nra:nwi_update_statewide_circ39&format=image/png&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&srs=EPSG:3857&width=500&height=500&bbox=-10476153.348653119,5789646.270432392,-10473707.363747992,5792092.255337515 with /**
2022-05-27 11:54:32,020 DEBUG [geoserver.monitor] - Testing /ows for monitor filtering
2022-05-27 11:54:32,024 TRACE [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher@731d22e6] and 1 interceptors
2022-05-27 11:54:32,024 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2022-05-27 11:54:32,024 DEBUG [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2022-05-27 11:54:32,024 DEBUG [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
2022-05-27 11:54:32,025 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Getting layers and styles from LAYERS and STYLES
2022-05-27 11:54:32,025 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - establishing nwi_update_circ39_keep style for nra:nwi_update_statewide_circ39
2022-05-27 11:54:32,025 INFO [geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] starting, processing through flow controllers
2022-05-27 11:54:32,025 DEBUG [geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] checking flow controller BasicOWSController(wfs.getfeature.=application/msexcel,org.geoserver.flow.controller.SimpleThreadBlocker@2e1c8b96)
2022-05-27 11:54:32,025 DEBUG [geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] passed flow controller BasicOWSController(wfs.getfeature.=application/msexcel,org.geoserver.flow.controller.SimpleThreadBlocker@2e1c8b96)
2022-05-27 11:54:32,025 DEBUG [geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] checking flow controller org.geoserver.flow.controller.UserConcurrentFlowController@74cf193f
2022-05-27 11:54:32,025 DEBUG [geoserver.flow] - UserFlowController(6,GS_CFLOW_-a575e67:17f12b24a67:-2bda) queue size 1
2022-05-27 11:54:32,025 DEBUG [geoserver.flow] - UserFlowController(6,GS_CFLOW_-a575e67:17f12b24a67:-2bda) total queues 1
2022-05-27 11:54:32,025 DEBUG [geoserver.flow] - UserFlowController(6) purged 0 stale queues
2022-05-27 11:54:32,025 DEBUG [geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] passed flow controller org.geoserver.flow.controller.UserConcurrentFlowController@74cf193f
2022-05-27 11:54:32,025 DEBUG [geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] checking flow controller BasicOWSController(wms.getmap,org.geoserver.flow.controller.SimpleThreadBlocker@347e2d12)
2022-05-27 11:54:32,025 DEBUG [geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] passed flow controller BasicOWSController(wms.getmap,org.geoserver.flow.controller.SimpleThreadBlocker@347e2d12)
2022-05-27 11:54:32,025 DEBUG [geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] checking flow controller BasicOWSController(gwc,org.geoserver.flow.controller.SimpleThreadBlocker@64c85cb0)
2022-05-27 11:54:32,026 DEBUG [geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] passed flow controller BasicOWSController(gwc,org.geoserver.flow.controller.SimpleThreadBlocker@64c85cb0)
2022-05-27 11:54:32,026 DEBUG [geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] checking flow controller GlobalFlowController(org.geoserver.flow.controller.SimpleThreadBlocker@2ec22b84)
2022-05-27 11:54:32,026 DEBUG [geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] passed flow controller GlobalFlowController(org.geoserver.flow.controller.SimpleThreadBlocker@2ec22b84)
2022-05-27 11:54:32,026 DEBUG [geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] checking flow controller RateFlowController [wps.execute, action=Delay excess requests 30000ms]
2022-05-27 11:54:32,026 DEBUG [geoserver.flow] - Request [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap] passed flow controller RateFlowController [wps.execute, action=Delay excess requests 30000ms]
2022-05-27 11:54:32,026 INFO [geoserver.flow] - Request control-flow performed, running requests: 1, blocked requests: 0
2022-05-27 11:54:32,026 DEBUG [geoserver.wms] - setting up map
2022-05-27 11:54:32,029 DEBUG [wms.map] - setting up 500x500 image
2022-05-27 11:54:32,029 DEBUG [wms.map] - setting to transparent
2022-05-27 11:54:32,030 DEBUG [renderer.lite] - Computed scale denominator: 17471.320750910254
2022-05-27 11:54:32,030 DEBUG [renderer.lite] - creating rules for scale denominator - 17,471.321
2022-05-27 11:54:32,030 DEBUG [renderer.label] - TOTAL LINE LABELS : 0
2022-05-27 11:54:32,031 DEBUG [renderer.label] - PAINTED LINE LABELS : 0
2022-05-27 11:54:32,031 DEBUG [renderer.label] - REMAINING LINE LABELS : 0
2022-05-27 11:54:32,031 DEBUG [renderer.lite] - Style cache hit ratio: NaN , hits 0, requests 0
2022-05-27 11:54:32,031 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getMap
    Angle = 0.0
    BaseUrl = http://nrri-atlas.d.umn.edu/geoserver/
    Bbox = SRSEnvelope[-1.0476153348653119E7 : -1.0473707363747992E7, 5789646.270432392 : 5792092.255337515]
    BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
    Buffer = 0
    Clip = null
    CQLFilter = null
    Crs = PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator", 
  GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
      SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
  PROJECTION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","1024"]], 
  PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
    Elevation = []
    Env = {}
    Exceptions = SE_XML
    FeatureId = null
    FeatureVersion = null
    Filter = null
    Format = image/png
    FormatOptions = {}
    Get = true
    Height = 500
    Interpolations = []
    Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@9dcd382f]
    MaxFeatures = null
    Palette = null
    RawKvp = {REQUEST=GetMap, FORMAT=image/png, SRS=EPSG:3857, BBOX=-10476153.348653119,5789646.270432392,-10473707.363747992,5792092.255337515, VERSION=1.1.1, SERVICE=WMS, WIDTH=500, HEIGHT=500, TRANSPARENT=true, LAYERS=nra:nwi_update_statewide_circ39}
    RemoteOwsType = null
    RemoteOwsURL = null
    Request = GetMap
    RequestCharset = UTF-8
    ScaleMethod = null
    Sld = null
    SldBody = null
    SldVersion = null
    SortBy = null
    SortByArrays = null
    SRS = EPSG:3857
    StartIndex = null
    StyleBody = null
    StyleFormat = sld
    Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=nwi_update_circ39_keep]]
    StyleUrl = null
    StyleVersion = null
    Tiled = false
    TilesOrigin = null
    Time = []
    Transparent = true
    ValidateSchema = false
    Version = 1.1.1
    ViewParams = null
    Width = 500
2022-05-27 11:54:32,031 DEBUG [wms.map] - Writing png image ...
2022-05-27 11:54:32,036 DEBUG [wms.map] - Writing png image ... done!
2022-05-27 11:54:32,036 DEBUG [geoserver.filters] - Not compressing output for mimetype: image/png
2022-05-27 11:54:32,037 INFO [geoserver.flow] - releasing flow controllers for [WMS 1.1.1 GetMap]
2022-05-27 11:54:32,037 INFO [geoserver.flow] - Request completed, running requests: 0, blocked requests: 0
2022-05-27 11:54:32,037 DEBUG [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: try removing `tileorigin` and `tiled` parameters

Comment: If you have problems with a certain style you should include the SLD of the style into your question. Perhaps the rules in the style does not hit any features in the data for some reason. The legend seems to be OK https://nrri-atlas.d.umn.edu/geoserver/ows?service=WMS&request=GetLegendGraphic&format=image%2Fpng&width=20&height=20&layer=nra%3Anwi_update_statewide_circ39.  The name of the style in GetCapabilities seems to be `nra:nwi_update_circ39_keep`.

Comment: It seems that layer is broken - but the other layers on the server mostly work, I would contact `nrriinfo@d.umn.edu` for more information on that layer.

Comment: @IanTurton For better or worse, I am the maintainer of this Geoserver instance...Any ideas how I can dig into why this layer is broken and find out how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the line `<sld:FeatureTypeName>nwi_statewide</sld:FeatureTypeName>` from the SLD definition got the layer drawing correctly.

This was an exceedingly frustrating nut to crack because there were no errors and no indication anything was wrong in the logs. In the end, it was just hours and days of trial and error to fix this.
Is there anyway the Geoserver devs can have the logs report back on issues like this? (I understand that this may be hopeless since an SLD may still be valid and not produce any output).

Comment: No errors were reported because technically there were no errors.  You requested the server to apply a style, but in that style there were no rules for the specific layer, so it applied no style and you get a blank image; that's the correct behaviour.